# How to handle bullying?

Tags: discussion

I've just encountered the following.

A user of linguistic SE, considering himself highly competent while in fact completely misunderstanding the topic, found his pride in bullying my question and explicitly voting it down.
It doesn't seem to me that he found the question as bad initially. He obviously got upset when I dared to disagree with his answer (which he at first bothered to write, incidentally). There is no constructive critique on his part, but a flood of angry comments.

What is an adequate procedure to fight trolls off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I looked where I should've gone first, the general SE Meta.

In [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112348/281321) the general advice is to keep calm, flag the troll's activity, and post the problem to the "local" Meta. Then, if one feels that the Moderators did not resolve the issue, the recommendation is to contact the head office ("contact us" button).